# Number Count animation angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

Hello I need to do the number counts with animation in angular 2 . I have a example in Jquery. I need to achieve this in angular 2. I need to do like the below example [`Codepen Example`](https://codepen.io/shivasurya/pen/FatiB)

Answer (score 5):

try below code :

> $ npm install ng2-odometer --save

**app.module.ts**

```
 import { Ng2OdometerModule } from 'ng2-odometer';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,FormsModule, 
    Ng2OdometerModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**home.html**

```
  <div style="font-size: 30px;color: white;">
        <ng2-odometer [number]="number" [config]="{ }"></ng2-odometer>
    </div>
```

**home.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public number: number = 1000;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

[more info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-odometer)

Comment: What is number is set from external api call than will odometer work or will need to use any sort of subscribe mechanism?

Comment: As ng2-odometer is old and not updated, I suggest using [angular2-counto](https://github.com/izupet/angular2-counto) package.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with the help of [RXJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/recipes/smartcounter.html). Additionally, we recently published a package [@bugsplat/ng-animated-counter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bugsplat/ng-animated-counter) that will do this for you.

**number-tracker.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { switchMap, startWith, scan, takeWhile, takeUntil, mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'number-tracker',
  template: `
    <h3> {{ currentNumber }}</h3>
  `
})
export class NumberTrackerComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @Input()
  set end(endRange: number) {
    this._counterSub$.next(endRange);
  }
  @Input() countInterval = 20;
  public currentNumber = 0;
  private _counterSub$ = new Subject();
  private _onDestroy$ = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this._counterSub$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(endRange => {
          return timer(0, this.countInterval).pipe(
            mapTo(this.positiveOrNegative(endRange, this.currentNumber)),
            startWith(this.currentNumber),
            scan((acc: number, curr: number) => acc + curr),
            takeWhile(this.isApproachingRange(endRange, this.currentNumber))
          )
        }),
        takeUntil(this._onDestroy$)
      )
      .subscribe((val: number) => this.currentNumber = val);
  }

  private positiveOrNegative(endRange, currentNumber) {
    return endRange > currentNumber ? 1 : -1;
  }

  private isApproachingRange(endRange, currentNumber) {
    return endRange > currentNumber
      ? val => val <= endRange
      : val => val >= endRange;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._onDestroy$.next();
    this._onDestroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

**usage**

```html
<p>
  <input
    type="number"
    (keyup.enter)="counterNumber = vanillaInput.value"
    #vanillaInput
  />
  <button (click)="counterNumber = vanillaInput.value">
    Update number
  </button>
</p>
<number-tracker [end]="counterNumber"></number-tracker>
```

Good luck!

Comment: `@bugsplat/ng-animated-counter` works like a charm. Is there a way to provide the duration for the counter? The animation tends to take a long time if the number is large, even if I set the `interval` to 0.

Comment: @DeepakDevanand checkout newly released version 1.2.1, we added an optional increment param that allows you to specify the number you count by. increasing this increment will decrease the total time the count takes. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a task with counting numbers when they appear in viewport - so, my usage:

`npm i ngx-countup` as a directive to animate counting, and my custom directive to figure out viewport appearing. No dependencies, no intersection observer, `ngx-countUp` supports Angular Universal.

**InViewport custom directive:**

HTML:

```
<div isInViewport (onView)="card.count = card.endCount" class="stats-count">
     <span *ngIf="card.count" [countUp]="card.count">0</span>
</div>
```

Directive code:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[isInViewport]',
})
export class IsInViewportDirective implements OnDestroy {
  private wasViewed$ = new Subject<void>();
  private subs = new Subscription();
  @Output() onView = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.listenScroll();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.wasViewed$.complete();
    this.subs.unsubscribe();
  }

  private listenScroll() {
    this.subs.add(
      fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.wasViewed$))
        .pipe(debounceTime(100))
        .subscribe(() => {
          if (this.isInViewport()) {
            this.onView.emit();
            this.wasViewed$.next();
            this.wasViewed$.complete();
          }
        })
    );
  }

  private isInViewport() {
    const elem = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    const bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      bounding.top >= 0 &&
      bounding.left >= 0 &&
      bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [IsInViewportDirective],
  exports: [IsInViewportDirective],
})
export class IsInViewportModule {}
```